# Django:Child Model Fields Not Rendering

Tags: python, django, forms, model, render

All Foreign Keys,Booleans and Choices fields are not rendering on the form template.But their label tags are rendering.
For example:
This is a "Generated TimeTable" model of a school system.
The model

```
class GT(models.Model):
        timetable_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=200)
        period_number = models.ForeignKey(Ref_Period,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        scheduled_date_and_time = models.ForeignKey(Ref_Calendar,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        schedule_id = models.ForeignKey(Planned_Timetable,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Ref_Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.teacher_id)
```

I already imported the  in the forms.py file 
forms.py

```
class GTForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GT
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
@login_required(login_url = 'main:loginPage')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])

def dalltt(request):

    gtform = GTForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
         gtform = GTForm(request.POST)
         print(gtform)
         if gtform.is_valid():
             gtform.save()
             print("saved")
             return redirect('/')
         else:
            print(gtform.errors)

    print(gtform)
    context = {'gtform':gtform}
    return render(request=request,template_name="main/dalltimetable.html",context=context)
```

The template(dalltimetable.html):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>{{ gtform.teacher_id.label_tag }} </th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ gtform.teacher_id }} </td>
            <td>{{ gtform.teacher_id }}</td>


        </tr>
    </table>




    <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Update">
    {{ form.name.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
@login_required(login_url = 'main:loginPage')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def dalltt(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         gtform = GTForm(request.POST)
         print(gtform)
         if gtform.is_valid():
             gtform.save()
             print("saved")
             return redirect('/')
         else:
            print(gtform.errors)
    else:
        gtform = GTForm()

    return render(request, 'main/dalltimetable.html', {'gtform': gtform })
```

Also maybe try switching to class-based views to help with the boilerplate:

```
class dalltt(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'main/dalltimetable.html'
    form_class = GTForm
    success_url = '/'
    login_url = 'main:loginPage'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
```